# Can I calculate the survival probability of a single time, t. By taking S(t+1) - S(t)?

Tags: distributions, survival

Since $\ S(t) = Pr(T > t) \ $ represents the probability that the variate takes a value greater than T. Is it correct to assume that the probability of survival at a single time t could be described as  $\ S(t+1) - S(t) \ $? And to take it one step further, could I assume that $\ 1 - (S(t+1) - S(t)) \ $ equates to the probability of not surviving at a point in time?

If I am wrong, is there a correct formula to be able to find the probability of not surviving at some discrete time t? (i.e., Probability that some row of a dataset terminates at t = 10?)

To give a more applied explanation, I have a survival dataset and I would like to generate a single probability of termination for t+1 (t = this month, t+1 = next month) for each row (each row represents a different record). I will be building this in either R or Python, I have no preference to either.

Comment: It sounds like you may be going in the direction of discrete time survival analysis. Here is one of my favorite papers on the topic: http://statisticalhorizons.com/wp-content/uploads/Allison.SM82.pdf

Comment: Thank you, @BenOgorek. I believe this is exactly what I have been hunting.

Comment: Note that S(t+1)<S(t) ...

Comment: Be sure this is what you really want. It's once thing to ask the probability that a newborn child will die at age 60. It is another to ask the probability that someone who has survived to 60 will die before 61. The latter is given by the hazard function.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about [discretization of continuous distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257261/how-to-set-a-discrete-gamma-prior/257268#257268). It can be applied to any continuous distribution with known survival function $S_X$ or cumulative distribution function $F_X$. If $X$ is a continuous random variable and $y = \lfloor x \rfloor $ is a greatest integer smaller or equal to $x$, then we can define *probability mass function* of $Y$ by taking

$$ f_Y(y) = F_X(y+1) - F_X(y) = S_X(y) - S_X(y + 1)$$

i.e. as $\Pr(Y=y)$ you take $\Pr(\lfloor x \rfloor < X \le \lfloor x \rfloor +1)$. Probability of surviving up to discrete time $y$ is, by above definition, $S_X(y + 1)$.